# Non-physicality of 'strings' in Kitaev's anyon model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, topological-order, anyons

I was reading Kitaev's paper on arXiv ([arXiv:quant-ph/9707021](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021), 'Fault-tolerant quantum computation by anyons') and was wondering if someone could clear something up for me about the non-physicality of strings joining anyons in the model.

Kitaev seems to claim that n-particle state depends only on the number and location of particles in the state. I suppose formally you'd say the state space is some quotient set of the full Hilbert space relative to the homotopy of the 'strings' connecting pairs of particles. On the face of it this is fine. I understand how there's no ambiguity in the case of one particle making a 360-degree rotation around the other since the topology of the 2D lattice means strings *must* cross regardless of their exact path.

However, suppose you have a state like this:

[image: 'Crossed' Kitaev anyons]

where 'z' labels the e-type particles and 'x' labels the m-type. You could write this as:

$$ |\psi\rangle = S^{z}(t) S^{x}(r) |0\rangle $$

where $|0\rangle$ is a vacuum/ground state. However, you could also write it like this:

$$ |\psi'\rangle = S^{x}(r) S^{z}(t) |0\rangle = -|\psi\rangle $$

where there's a minus sign since $S^{x}(r)$ and $S^{z}(t)$ anti-commute due to the $\sigma^{z}$ and $\sigma^{x}$ on the same site at the intersection. To me this seems like it's impossible to disregard the strings as unphysical. You could just as easily have a state where the particles are in the same locations but the strings don't intersect, and then the 'order of creation' has no effect on the phase.

To see that this is important consider a situation where you create the superposition:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\psi\rangle + |\psi'\rangle\right) $$

this state is the zero vector if the strings intersect, or a valid non-zero state if they don't. So how can you just look at particle position and ignore the strings? Or did I miss something in the paper where he specifies strings shouldn't intersect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting IRL with some people, we've determined the answer.

The Hamiltonian for the system, $H$, is highly degenerate with a class of ground states:

$$ \mathcal{H} \supseteq \mathcal{H}_{G} = \{|\psi\rangle : A_{s}|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle \land B_{p}|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\} $$

where $A_s$ and $B_p$ are the toric code stabilisers.

The superposition defined in the question (with intersecting paths) falls into this category, so it is in fact a ground state not an excited state. Any "4 particle" state that is actually excited (i.e., has an energy of 8 above the ground state) is path independent.

For the above superposition no measurement you could do on the lattice with the A and B operators would tell you it's a superposition of excited states instead of just a vacuum state.